# Objects - Adding Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

> You are provided with an array, possibleIterable. Using a for loop,
> build out the object divByThree so that each key is an element of
> possibleIterable that is divisible by three. The value of each key
> should be the array index at which that key can be found in
> possibleIterable.

```js
const possibleIterable = [4, 3, 9, 6, 23];
const divByThree = {};
// ADD CODE HERE
for(let i= 0; i < possibleIterable.length; i++){
 if( possibleIterable[i] % 3 == 0) {
 divByThree[i] =  possibleIterable[i] + i ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so that each key is an element of possibleIterable that is divisible
> by three

This means as key you have to give the value `possibleIterables[i]` and not the indice `i`.

> The value of each key should be the array index at which that key can
> be found in possibleIterable.

The value is its position inside the array -> the indice `i`.

```
 divByThree[possibleIterable[i]] =  i
```

```js
const possibleIterable = [4, 3, 9, 6, 23];
const divByThree = {};
// ADD CODE HERE
for(let i= 0; i < possibleIterable.length; i++){
 if( possibleIterable[i] % 3 === 0) {
  divByThree[possibleIterable[i]] =  i;
 }
}

console.log(divByThree);
```